# Authentication in MongoDB is not working in Azure Container Instance when deploying with Azure File Share as mount volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, yaml, azure-cli

I am deploying MongoDB container as Azure container instance in a group using Azure CLI YAML script. Here I am using a Azure file share as a mount volume, while using this mount volume the authentication is not enabled in MongoDB. Though without mount volume it is working fine. Here is my YAML script:

```
apiVersion: '2019-12-01'
location: eastus
name: api-service
properties:
containers:
 - name: mongo-db
 properties:
  image: serviceregistry.azurecr.io/apiservice_mongo-db:latest
  ports:
   - port: 27017
  environmentVariables:
   - name: MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE
     value: logsdb
   - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
     value: root
   - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
    secureValue: mypass
  resources:
   requests:
    cpu: 1.0
    memoryInGB: 1.5
 volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /data/mongodata
    name: mongofileshare
 command: ['mongod', '--dbpath', '/data/mongodata'] #if i comment this line works fine
 - name: log-api
  properties:
   environmentVariables: []
   image: serviceregistry.azurecr.io/apiservice_log-api:latest
   ports:
    - port: 3100
   resources:
    requests:
     cpu: 1.0
     memoryInGB: 1.5
 - name: mongo-express
   properties:
   image: mongo-express:latest
   ports:
    - port: 8081
   environmentVariables:
    - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
      value: 127.0.0.1
    - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT
      value: 27017
    - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
      value: root
    - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
      secureValue: mypass
    - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME
      value: admin
    - name: ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD
      secureValue: mypass
   resources:
    requests:
     cpu: 1.0
     memoryInGB: 1.5
 osType: Linux
 restartPolicy: OnFailure
 ipAddress:
  type: Public
 ports:
  - protocol: tcp
    port: 3100
  - protocol: tcp
    port: 8081
  - protocol: tcp
    port: 27017
 dnsNameLabel: serviceapidns
 volumes:
  - name: mongofileshare
    azureFile:
     sharename: mysharefile
     storageAccountName: myaccount
     storageAccountKey: mykey
 imageRegistryCredentials:
  server: serviceregistry.azurecr.io
  username: MyUserName
  password: MyPass
 tags: {}
 type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

I got this:

```
msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-256","principalName":"root","authenticationDatabase":"admin","client":"127.0.0.1:44566","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "root" for db "admin""}}
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) regarding the use of these environment variables? This part might be of particular interest: ***"Do note that none of the variables below will have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be left untouched on container startup."***

Comment: Hi Bruno Cardoso, I stumbled upon this problem, too. Did you figure out how to make authentication in Azure working again? Do you have dome solution? Thx. in advance.

Comment: @Mysiaq I also face this issue, any luck?